# Sufficient statistics for $\theta$ with a given distribution $p_{\theta} = (\sin{\theta})^{x} (\cos{2 \theta})^{2x}$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Let $p_{\theta}$ be a family of distributions given by $$p_{\theta} = (\sin{\theta})^{x} (\cos{2 \theta})^{2x}$$
defined for  $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$ and $\theta \in [a, \frac{\pi}{2}]$, where $a$ is some known constant, $\theta$ is the unknown parameter. Here the density is defined with respect to the counting measure on $\mathbb{Z}_{+}$.

What are the possible ways to find a sufficient statistics $T(X)$ for $X = (X_{1}, X_{2}, \ldots, X_{n})$, where each $X_{i}$ is distributed as above?

As indicated in many examples, it's pretty straightforward to intently look at the multivariate density of $X$ and apply the Fisher-Neyman factorization theorem, though in the case above it may look a little obfuscating.

Comment: Does $\sum X_k$ not do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Neyman-Fisher criteria you have that
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n \left( \sin (\theta) \cos^2 ( 2\theta )\right)^{x_i} = \left( \sin (\theta) \cos^2 ( 2\theta )\right)^{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i},
$$
hence $T(X) = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.